# i got listed in XBL/CBL but the computer does not contain malware

Tags: windows-7, malware, spam-prevention

We got blocked because we were listed in CBL for the following reason:

> This IP is infected with, or is NATting for a machine infected with
>   Torpig, also known by Symantec as Anserin.
>
> This was detected by observing this IP attempting to make contact to a
>   Torpig Command and Control server at 217.160.140.127, with contents
>   unique to Torpig C&C command protocols.

The computer is in a NATted network connected to the internet with a dedicated IP. 
The firewall and DHCP logs pointed us to the right computer.

I scanned the computer using MBAM, Norman, TDDS Killer, Norton, Super Anti Spyware, Symantec Root Kit Killer and from Ubuntu with Clamav but none of them found a virus.

So, was my computer really infected? I won't take any risk and will reformat the computer, but this is really weird that a virus can exist on my computer and 7 AV products will not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanning from a separate OS is a good idea, especially when an active rootkit has to be expected, but ClamAV might not be the best choice to hunt down such an infection. I suggest to use a product with better detection rates for malware files found on infected machines, e. g. Avira's Rescue System, which runs from a boot cd or a flashdrive:  http://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-antivir-rescue-system

Or maybe this system is not infected at all and you made a mistake while tracking the source of the request? Are you sure about the association of ip address and machine?

Comment: I am 100% definately sure about the IP/machine. I have formatted and reinstalled the OS on the machine but will keep your tip for next time